# What kind of Dell Perc H710 card is a "VM02C"?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, sas, dell-perc

A number of vendors (e.g., on eBay) sell a Perc H710 card they say is a part number VM02C. However, I can't find this in Dell's website, either by looking at every H710 card list in the parts area, or using the site-wide search, or even using Google search with site:dell.com. A chat with one of the vendors indicates *they* are certain it's a Dell part, and I have no reason to doubt them. I think the part numbers they have are simply from a different type of database or else I'm looking in the wrong place.

Does anyone know what a "VM02C-HIGH P" card corresponds to, in terms of Dell part numbers? Here are the things that I can find that look plausibly like the pictures on Dell's website:

- [Manufacturer Part# : 2YP62, Dell Part# : 342-3631](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=342-3631)
- [Manufacturer Part# : 8PX3M, Dell Part# : 342-4203](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19s&sku=342-4203)
- [Manufacturer Part# : PCVT5, Dell Part# : 342-3536](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=fed&cs=16&sku=342-3536)

(In case it matters, I'm trying to find a card that will work properly in a Dell T420, and was hoping to save some $$ by getting a used card.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part VM02C is listed in Dell's internal DBs as "PERC H710 Adapter - FH Gen 3"

I'm not sure what those 3 part numbers are (they turn up as invalid with my searches), but the model you're looking at online should be fully compatible with your system.

Here are all the part numbers listed as available for "dispatch" for the T420:

- VM02C  PERC H710 Adapter - FH Gen 3
- 0GJKT  Card Assembly, PERC H710, 512MB, NVD, Low Profile
- 17MXW  Card Assembly, PERC H710, 512MB, NVD, Full Height
- V1HXY  H710 Adapter - LP
- NHD8V  H710 Adapter - FH
- 1KJ7G  PERC H710 Adapter - LP Gen 3

Comment: I see other models aside from these online when I simply search for "H710 T420" - I'd recommend sticking to the list to be on the safe side though.

Comment: Thanks for properly tagging your question! That tends to get the right eyes on things, as many users subscribe to specific tags.

Comment: I edited the question to add links to the pages describing the particular three part numbers I listed, to make it easier for future readers to figure out what I was talking about ...